# Pattern to wait on downloaded data

Tags: design-patterns, android

I am wondering how I should solve one issue.

When I start an Activity, I download some data using an `AsyncTask`.

When the user selects an option on the menu, I use the cached data.

What if he selects the options while data is still downloading? 
What is the best way to wait for the data without blocking the UI?

**edit**: I don't want to change the menu/make the option disabled. I want to show a spinner while waiting for the data to finish its download.

Thanks

Comment: consider setting a flag isDoneDownloading to false and check this flag when the user tries to use the data from the menu returning useful user feedback. Set the flag to true in onPostExecute. This will not stop the user from doing other things in the UI while the data is downloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable/enable the items in the onMenuOpened() :

```
@Override
  public boolean onMenuOpened(int feature, Menu menu) {
    if (menu != null) {
      menu.getItem(INDEX_FOR_THE_MENU_ITEM).setEnabled(stuffIsAvailable);
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(feature, menu);
  }
```

EDIT - showing a progress dialog:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
dialog.setMessage(context.getString(dialogTextResourceId));
dialog.show();
```

Don't forget to `dialog.dismiss(`) it when you're done.

Comment: That's a solution, but I don't want to change the menu, I would prefer to put a spinner while waiting the end of the download. I'll updated my question. Thanks for the idea

Comment: Right, then you can show a ProgressDialog while you wait. Edited the answer.

Comment: Sure, but how do I detect the end of the download?

Comment: Using AsyncTasks? The AsyncTask has an onPostExecute() method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

You can call `AsyncTask.getStatus()` when the menu option is pressed and if it is still running then display the ProgressDialog.

Then in `AsyncTask.onPostExeute()` you can tell your Activity the data is available and dismiss the spinner.

Comment: What if I have: 1. in main: getStatus == RUNNING. 2. In Asyntask; tasks finishes and dismisses the dialog. 3. in main: the main got held, and only shows the dialog now. It gets locked forever :/

Comment: Well once the user presses the menu item and the data is not ready what do you want main to do?  If you just want it to display a spinner while it waits, why not just block the UI and start the spinner in main.  Then when AsyncTask finishes it can tell main and main can then dismiss the spinner and use the data.

Answer (score 0):

Run an uncancellable progress dialog when the download is initiated, dismiss once the download is done. Read up on the `ProgressDialog` class.

Comment: I don't want to block the user when downloading in background! He may not want to use the data right after the download.

Comment: @Jonas: if you don't want to disable menu items, and don't want to make them otherwise unavailable (via a modal ProgressDialog), insert a check for download status into menu item handlers and flash a AlertDialog to the effect of "Try again later".